# Compactness properties in floer homology of cotangent bundles in the non-periodic case

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology

Following the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408280.pdf  I have been interested in studying the case of solutions $x:[0,1] \rightarrow T^*M$ such that $x(0)\in T_{q_0}^*M$ and $x(1)\in T_{q_1}^*M$ for $q_0,q_1 \in M$.

It is claimed that by using $L^{\infty}$ estimates one can show that the moduli spaces $\mathcal{M}(x^-,x^+)$ are pre-compact in  $C^{\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}\times [0,1],T^*M)$.  To do this I belive one can just adapt the argument that is done in floer theory for the periodic case and use the $L^{\infty}$ estimates to be able to use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

However I am having some difficulty in proving that we have uniform gradient bounds in the space $\mathcal{M}(x^{-},x^{+})$. I have tried to follow the argument for the periodic case but I was not able to obtain in this case a holomorphic disk with boundary in either $T_{q_0}^*M$ or $T_{q_1}^*M.$

Any enlightment is appreciated, thanks in advance .

Comment: What exactly is the moduli space you are considering? I don't understand the problem you are studying.